# how to find out when a method from an object is called in java

Tags: java

I have two classes, e.g. A and B.

An instance of A creates an instance of class B. How can A become aware when an specific function from object B is called?

Object A needs to become aware whenever an specific function from object B is executed, but without changing the source code of class B. This should be done at run-time.

I guess it can be done by InvocationHandler in java, but not sure and don't know how to do it.

Comment: this could be a case for aspect oriented programming

Comment: or proxy, but AOP is more elegant for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to decorate `B` so that `decordatedB.someMethod()` first notifies `a` and then calls `d.someMethod()`.

If `B` is an interface, it is quite easy, you do something like

```
final B b = new BImpl();
final B decoratedB = new B() {
  public void someMethod () {
    a.someMethodOfBisCalled();
    b.someMethod();
  }
};
```

If `B` is a class then you could use [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) (very rough sketch):

```
InvocationHandler bInvocationHandler = new BInvocationHandler() {
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
       // Check this is someMethod
       // a.someMethodOfBIsCalled();
       // b.someMethod();
    }
};

B decoratedB = (B) Proxy.newProxyInstance(B.class.getClassLoader(),
    new Class[] { Foo.class }, bInvocationHandler );
```

There are other ways like mentioned AOP, then code instrumentation etc. etc. but I think you are well served with the above.

Answer (score 1):

what about a decorator of B that notifies A ?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: this or AOP, depending on if something else beyond count increment, must be done in wrapper.

Comment: I think, you can't really say it's AOP without knowing the reasons behind the OP's intention. If it's SoC, then OK, but there may be much simpler cases.